# Are any identities of the form $t(a+b)$ known, where $t(n)$ is the $n^{\rm th}$ element of the Thue-Morse sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics-on-words

Let $t(n)$ denote the $n^{\rm th}$ element of the Thue Morse sequence, i.e.,  $t(n)=1$ if the number of $1$s in the binary expansion of $n$ is odd, $0$ otherwise. Let also $t(0)=0$.

It is easy show that

- $t(2n)=t(n)$,
- $t(2n+1)=1-t(n)$.

Now let $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$ and greater than $0$. Can anything be proven about $t(a+b)$ for any specific (or general) values of $a$ and $b$? I have not found any identities of this form in the available literature.

Answer (score 1):

If there are $c$ carries in the binary addition $a+b$, then $t(a+b) \equiv t(a) + t(b) + c \mod 2$.

EDIT: $c$ is also the $2$-adic valuation of ${a+b \choose a}$, by [Kummer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer's_theorem)